# How to import Pascal VOC 2012 segmentation dataset to Google Colab?

Tags: image-segmentation, data-pipeline

I am new in building data pipe-line. I want to import [Pascal VOC dataset](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2012/VOCtrainval_11-May-2012.tar) into Google Colab.

Can some please point to me a good Google Colab/Jupyter notebook file?

Answer (score 0):

You can download a file from google drive using gdown,the pascal voc dataset is already uploaded on drive so you can use the following commends,

```
!gdown https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1-7H7hdaaLZnYidfi0faQdq7Dn0CFhDOA
!unzip cl-rg-objectsdetection-recognization.zip.com%2F20210327%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request\&X-Goog-Date\=20210327T174906Z\&X-Goog-Expires\=259199\&X-Goog-SignedHeaders\=hos
```